# If $\frac{t^2-x^2}{(t^2+x^2)^2}+\frac{(1-x)^2-t^2}{((1-x)^2+t^2)^2}=0$ for real $t$ and $0<x<1$, prove that $x=1/2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods, roots

> $$\frac{t^2-x^2}{(t^2+x^2)^2}+\frac{(1-x)^2-t^2}{((1-x)^2+t^2)^2}=0$$ 
>   where $0<x<1$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $x=1/2$.

It is evident that $x=1/2$ satisfies the above equation. Please help.

Comment: What do you need help with? It looks like you're already done with this problem to me.

Comment: If you combine the fractions and factor the numerator, you get a factor of $(1-2x)$ (confirming that $x=1/2$ is a root) as well as a messy polynomial in $x$ and $t$. What do you know (or what might the author of the problem *expect* you to know) about proving whether a polynomial has roots in a given interval? The more context you can provide, the easier you make it for someone to help you.

Comment: @Blue I just want x=1/2. So is that messy polynomial is non zero ?

Comment: @Divide1918 I just want x=1/2

Comment: @Shekharsuman: Well, you're correct that it's "evident" $x=1/2$ is a solution. (We often say that something like this is true "by inspection".) My reading of the question is that you want to show that $x=1/2$ is the *only* solution; that is, you have to rule everything else out, so you'd have to prove that the messy polynomial has no $x$-roots between $0$ and $1$. Is this not your interpretation of the problem?

Comment: Btw, the 'messy polynomial' is [$-3 t^4 - 2 t^2 x^2 + 2 t^2 x - t^2 + x^4 - 2 x^3 + x^2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28t%5E2-x%5E2%29*%28%28%281-x%29%5E2%2Bt%5E2%29%5E2%29%2B%28%28t%5E2%2Bx%5E2%29%5E2%29*%28%281-x%29%5E2-t%5E2%29%29%2F%28x-1%2F2%29). Just cleared the denominator and divided by $x-\frac12$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: I concur. :)  That said, given how the problem is presented, I wonder if there's a way to proceed without bothering to factor. It would help if OP provided some context to the problem so that we'd know what kinds of techniques are intended to be applied, and/or whether a "clever" approach is expected.

Comment: What about applying the IVT?

Comment: As hint I make the substitution $cos(a)=t$ and $sin(a)=x$ we see that there is other roots  differents of $0.5$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28cos%28x%29%C2%B2-sin%28x%29%C2%B2%29%2F%28cos%28x%29%C2%B2%2Bsin%28x%29%C2%B2%29%C2%B2%2B%28%281-sin%28x%29%29%C2%B2-cos%28x%29%C2%B2%29%2F%28%281-sin%28x%29%29%C2%B2%2Bcos%28x%29%C2%B2%29%C2%B2%3D0 . Good luck !

Comment: @Mister.Expandead I don't think the solution for x can depend on t in the question. Also by letting $cos(a)=t$ you're assuming extra restriction on t

Comment: @Divide1918 Is the statement that x=1/2 is the only solution correct?

Comment: @Shekharsuman It is, I don't think my current solution has any defects.

Comment: It is not the only solution for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. For example set $t = 1/4$. Then there are 3 solutions for $0 < x < 1$

Comment: @thinkingeye I think the question is asking for a solution for x between 0 and 1 such that the equation is true no matter what value of t is chosen. The two extra roots for x which is not equal to 1/2 may not satisfy the equation for another t

Comment: @thinkingeye but for $t=0$ we must certainly have $x=1/2$, so is the value of $x$ dependent on $t$? Because I posted an answer substituting with $t=0$, and Shekhar suman told me that the $t$ is specific, not variable, so we can't make such substitution

Comment: Well, it depends on the author. $x = 1/2$ is indeed the only solution which is true for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ as it does not depend on $t$. But there exists also other solution which depends on $t$.

Comment: @Shekharsuman I added an important edit, please look at it, it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, define $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x=1-y$ (noting that also $0<y<1$), we get
$$\frac{t^2-x^2}{(t^2+x^2)^2}+\frac{(1-x)^2-t^2}{((1-x)^2+t^2)^2}=0$$
$$\implies \frac{t^2-(1-y)^2}{(t^2+(1-y)^2)^2}+\frac{y^2-t^2}{(y^2+t^2)^2}=0$$
Note that the first equation implies 
$$\frac{t^2-x^2}{(t^2+x^2)^2}=\frac{t^2-(1-x)^2}{((1-x)^2+t^2)^2}$$
While the second implies 
$$\frac{t^2-(1-y)^2}{(t^2+(1-y)^2)^2}=\frac{t^2-y^2}{(y^2+t^2)^2}$$
So, in fact, the two equations are equivalent, which means $y=x \implies 1-x=x \implies x=1/2$

Edit: I figured out that what I proved was if $a$ is a solution (for $x$) then $1-a$ is also a solution. This means that $x=1/2$ for sure is a solution for all $t$.

But when I tried graphing the equation on desmos and added a slider for $t$, I get that as $t$ ranges over all reals (or $t^2$ ranges over positive reals), $x$ and $1-x$ vary with it. For example, $t^2 = \frac{1}{6}\left(\sqrt{601} - 13\right) \implies x \in \{-2,1/2,3\}$

Note that $x=1/2$ is the general solution, and $x=3$ is a specific solution and if $3$ is a solution then $1-3=-2$ is also a solution.

If we want $x=4$ as a solution we have $x=1-4=-3$ is also a solution and $t^2=\frac{1}{6}\left(\sqrt{2353} - 25\right)$ satisfies the equation. So, there's no point of solving for a specific $x$ if $x$ just varies depending on $t^2$ over the reals (and of course $1-x$ accordingly), but for all $t$, $x=1/2$ is certainly a solution.

Comment: Damn that's really clever.

Comment: @Divide1918 Thank you! I can't express how happy I became from this comment xD

Comment: Take $t^2<\frac{1}{12}$ and [see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28t%5E2-x%5E2%29%2F%28%28t%5E2%2Bx%5E2%29%5E2%29%2B%28%281-x%29%5E2-t%5E2%29%2F%28%28%281-x%29%5E2%2Bt%5E2%29%5E2%29%3D0%2C+t%5E2%3D1%2F13%2C+0%3Cx%3C1)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin yea, there's a problem with the problem

Comment: What I proved was only that if $x$ is a solution then $1-x$ is also a solution and this implies that for all $t$, we have $x=\frac{1}{2}$. But for specific $t$ we don't know if we can get all values of $x$ for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the fastest way to show this is indeed considering the polynomial left after clearing the denominator and dividing by $2(x-\frac{1}{2})$
[$$f(x)=-3 t^4 - 2 t^2 x^2 + 2 t^2 x - t^2 + x^4 - 2 x^3 + x^2$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28t%5E2-x%5E2%29*%28%28%281-x%29%5E2%2Bt%5E2%29%5E2%29%2B%28%28t%5E2%2Bx%5E2%29%5E2%29*%28%281-x%29%5E2-t%5E2%29%29%2F%28x-1%2F2%29)
Considering [$$f'(x)= -2 (2 x - 1) (t^2 - x^2 + x)$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-3+t%5E4+-+2+t%5E2+x%5E2+%2B+2+t%5E2+x+-+t%5E2+%2B+x%5E4+-+2+x%5E3+%2B+x%5E2%29%27) we see that as $(t^2+x(1-x))>0$ for $0<x<1$ thus the function increases on $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and decreases on $\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$ thus we have to check only that $f(0),\,f\left(\frac12\right),\,f(1)$ has the same sign, indeed:
$$f(0)=-3t^4-t^2\le 0$$ $$f(1)=-3t^4-t^2\le 0$$ 
[$$f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-3 t^4 - \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{1}{16}$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-3+t%5E4+-+2+t%5E2+x%5E2+%2B+2+t%5E2+x+-+t%5E2+%2B+x%5E4+-+2+x%5E3+%2B+x%5E2+where+x+%3D+1%2F2)
But the latter expression factors as
$$-\frac{1}{16} (4 t^2 + 1) (12 t^2 - 1)$$
so for $12t^2-1<0$ the statement is not true.
$$$$

Comment: so how does the same sign of f(0),f(1/2)and f(1) suffice the proof???

Comment: The function $f(x)=\left(\frac{t^2-x^2}{(t^2+x^2)^2}+\frac{(1-x)^2-t^2}{((1-x)^2+t^2)^2}\right)(t^2+x^2)^2((1-x)^2+t^2)^2\frac{1}{2x-1}$ by inspection of $f'(x)$ has only one maximum on $(0,1)$, namely $\frac{1}{2}$ and no other extremum points. If the signs of function values at the interval ends and the maximum are the same, then all signs of function values over $(0,1)$ are the same, is it correct?